# Python 3.11.1. Getting error Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, saprfc

I am using zeep 4.2.1 library to consume web services (RFC) from SAP. The API's are working in local server and getting the necessary response. However the API is not working in development environment (docker container).

Getting error message as

> HTTPConnectionPool(host=' ', port=): Max retries exceeded with url. (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffa989589b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname',))

After doing telnet from development environment response received, it gets connected but after sometime (1 min approx) this error is raised and connection is closed:

> 408 "Request Time Out" Application Server Error - Traffic control Violation

Note: I have removed hostname from error message but hostname and port are correct. `HTTPConnectionPool(host=' ', port=)`

Kindly help me does any additional setting required for SAP RFC in docker container

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: `to consume web services (RFC)` RFC is not a web-service, is another technology. Please give the code what and how do you consume